# Why is JsonContent not populating before SendAsync?

Tags: json, .net-core, azure-logic-apps

I'm using a .NET Core console application to send JSON data to an Azure Logic App. If the JSON data is a short list of data e.g. 4 items then everything works. For more data I have to evaluate the Content of the HttpRequestMessage before sending otherwise the Azure Logic App reports empty content. Is there any alternative to forcing evaluation, it feels counter intuitive.

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            
var postRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri)
{
    Content = JsonContent.Create(data)//data is a list object
};

//need this line to evaluate the content before posting otherwise content is empty according to Azure Logic App
await postRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

using var postResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(postRequest);

postResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

This code structure seems to feature in a lot of tutorials without the call to postRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() without anyone experiencing similar problems.

An example of the JSON that fails would be:

```
[{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.23","name":"AuditLog","rows":3859209,"reservedKb":22061528,"dataKb":8781560,"reservedIndexSize":66328,"reservedUnused":13213640,"dbName":"DBOne"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.23","name":"AnswerData","rows":70167,"reservedKb":12586736,"dataKb":12494912,"reservedIndexSize":1472,"reservedUnused":90352,"dbName":"DBOne"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.23","name":"Data_import","rows":3623146,"reservedKb":722632,"dataKb":379704,"reservedIndexSize":1424,"reservedUnused":341504,"dbName":"DBOne"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.23","name":"Answers","rows":2036892,"reservedKb":528872,"dataKb":270096,"reservedIndexSize":257360,"reservedUnused":1416,"dbName":"DBOne"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.23","name":"Data","rows":3623146,"reservedKb":381256,"dataKb":379704,"reservedIndexSize":1424,"reservedUnused":128,"dbName":"DBOne"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.23","name":"Data_backup","rows":3623146,"reservedKb":380048,"dataKb":379704,"reservedIndexSize":16,"reservedUnused":328,"dbName":"DBOne"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.23","name":"datadec","rows":3623146,"reservedKb":252168,"dataKb":232952,"reservedIndexSize":8,"reservedUnused":19208,"dbName":"DBOne"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.23","name":"SalesDetails","rows":84168,"reservedKb":170496,"dataKb":138104,"reservedIndexSize":20136,"reservedUnused":12256,"dbName":"DBOne"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.23","name":"OurUsers","rows":66145,"reservedKb":72240,"dataKb":37880,"reservedIndexSize":32776,"reservedUnused":1584,"dbName":"DBOne"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.23","name":"Orders","rows":362720,"reservedKb":70016,"dataKb":53608,"reservedIndexSize":11976,"reservedUnused":4432,"dbName":"DBOne"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.597","name":"CustDetails","rows":8949,"reservedKb":16392,"dataKb":15704,"reservedIndexSize":80,"reservedUnused":608,"dbName":"DBTwo"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.597","name":"OurUsers","rows":5580,"reservedKb":6096,"dataKb":4456,"reservedIndexSize":1600,"reservedUnused":40,"dbName":"DBTwo"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.597","name":"Answers","rows":56835,"reservedKb":5184,"dataKb":5104,"reservedIndexSize":32,"reservedUnused":48,"dbName":"DBTwo"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.597","name":"UserRoles","rows":5577,"reservedKb":4632,"dataKb":1496,"reservedIndexSize":3056,"reservedUnused":80,"dbName":"DBTwo"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.597","name":"CustDetails","rows":5866,"reservedKb":1928,"dataKb":1864,"reservedIndexSize":16,"reservedUnused":48,"dbName":"DBTwo"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.597","name":"OrderHistories","rows":6102,"reservedKb":1224,"dataKb":1168,"reservedIndexSize":16,"reservedUnused":40,"dbName":"DBTwo"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.597","name":"Orders","rows":6196,"reservedKb":1224,"dataKb":1176,"reservedIndexSize":16,"reservedUnused":32,"dbName":"DBTwo"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.597","name":"Transfers","rows":7522,"reservedKb":840,"dataKb":816,"reservedIndexSize":16,"reservedUnused":8,"dbName":"DBTwo"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.597","name":"SalesDetails","rows":8762,"reservedKb":648,"dataKb":576,"reservedIndexSize":16,"reservedUnused":56,"dbName":"DBTwo"},{"runDate":"2021-02-18T16:30:11.597","name":"TransferAdvice","rows":13706,"reservedKb":392,"dataKb":328,"reservedIndexSize":16,"reservedUnused":48,"dbName":"DBTwo"}]
```

Comment: Unable to replicate.

Comment: I've added an example of a JSON payload that fails for me. Smaller datasets work without the ReadAsStringAsync line but anything this large seems to need to be evaluated directly.

Comment: wait, what? You are calling `ReadAsStringAsync` and THEN you call `SendAsync` ?! How in the world is *that* supposed to work?

Comment: @Andy That's what I'd have thought but it only works if I do that. It's like the JSON content isn't being populated before I send it if I don't read it beforehand.

Comment: And I should point it I'm reading the content of the request before sending it not reading the response itself.

Comment: You won't get an answer because your code is broken by design. It's illogical. You can't read from a content stream that doesn't exist. That `Content` object you are reading from is used for *writing* a body to your request when `SendAsync` is called. You would *then* read from `postResponse.Content` *after* the call to `SendAsync`

Comment: @Andy, thanks for replying. I don't want to read the Content before I send it but what I'm observing is that when my JSON content goes over a certain size if I don't do something that evaluates the content before posting then it doesn't seem to be in the request object by the time it hits my logic app so that's the only way I can get it to actually work. I fully understand it isn't logical but I'm trying to understand why it does work and what I can do to correct the logic failure.

Comment: According to the comments made to https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45587, the problem seems to be about missing Content-Length. I have had this issue as well and fixed it by replacing JsonContent with StringContent.